# Build PhoneGap app to specific Android version

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

Is there any way to build a phonegap project into a specific `android` api version? No matter if it's at the adding, or building the project. Can't find any way to pass the required api version for any of below commands

```
$phonegap platform add android
$phonegap build android
```

Thinking of something like

```
$phonegap build android 17
```

If it help's to answer, am on Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@highfive,
this is an item missing in the Phonegap CLI documentation. You can use the [Phonegap Build documentation](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/2.9.0/configuring_preferences.md.html) to help, but issues when using this documentation. Namely, config.xml is stored in the `www/` directory, instead of the project directory - like Phonegap CLI.

This blog post will help:

[PhoneGap 3.0 – Stuff You Should Know](http://devgirl.org/2013/09/05/phonegap-3-0-stuff-you-should-know/)

In the end, you will need to add: `android-minSdkVersion`. Like this:

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="17" />`

Jesse

Comment: This guides me to the solution. I added `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="17" />` in the myApp/config.xml file